# How can I create after startup on database (or server) trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm new here. Could you please tell me what should I do to create trigger on server launching (starting)? I have to use trigger in MS SQL SERVER

Answer (score 2):

You can use either

- SQL Server Agent, which has a "on start up" option for scheduling
- Use [sp_procoption](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191129(v=sql.105).aspx) and the "scan for startup procs" configuation option

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how to use it in triggers. I have to do (trigger should do) some actions on server launch

Comment: There is no way to use a trigger to run code at startup. My answers describes the only 2 sensible ways to run code on SQL Server startup.